# How do I run node.js in my Java script code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm quite new to web developing (a week or so in) and I understand I may be moving too quickly but I need some help as I don't quite understand this. What I have so far is a login page that compares the 2 inputs (username + password) to 2 constant variables. However the way I want it to work is comparing the inputs to 2 values I read from a text file, so I can have like a database of usernames/passwords.

```
 <script>

const adminUserName = "admin";
const adminPassWord = "123";


function getUsername(){
var username = document.getElementById("userName").value;
var password = document.getElementById("passWord").value;

username == adminUserName && password == adminPassWord ? window.open ("admin.html","mywindow"):
document.write("Invalid entry.")
```

}

and the code I need to add (node.js) is

```
    var fs = require('fs')
    fs.readFile('loginData.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data){
    })
```

so how do I connect node.js to my website?
Sorry if I haven't explained well, also if you have a better idea for storing user data please feel free to explain (remember im new) :)

Comment: You're asking about two completely different things here; NodeJS has nothing to do with reading data from a text file - raw JavaScript can handle this. Also, you *really* shouldn't use text files to store passwords in the first place. You should be calling off to a server-side database to handle any authentication. If you do indeed want NodeJS (it's optional to achieve this), it's something you'll need to download manually from [**NodeJs.Org**](https://nodejs.org/en/), and it will allow you to use the NodeJS Package Manager ([**NPM**](https://flaviocopes.com/npm/)).

Comment: What you want is actually not possible, since, in a browser you can NOT read from the local filesystem like that, fortunately, since if you could, surfing the internet would be completely unsafe

Comment: is there no way I could use a txt file thats on the web server and read from that?

Comment: What you want is to have your client code make a request to your server code.  So your script tag would perhaps use an AJAX request to hit a Node API endpoint.  You could use NPM to install a framework for APIs (like Express).  Each of those has pretty great documentation, so you'll want to work on your client code and server code both.

Comment: Node.js and the browser are both entirely different contexts that both can run JavaScript.  Filesystem APIs like `fs` are provided by Node.

Comment: Everyone is guessing what you are trying to do. This is a classic symptom of an XY problem. Describe what your objective is, not just what how to use a mechanism (that experienced developers know don't work) to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution before the answer: If you are new to website development and you are needing to make usernames and passwords, I want to caution you against putting vulnerable info pass the username and password wall. There are many sophisticated and non-sophisticated methods for getting behind passwords and usernames. Sometimes, this can be a struggle for experienced programmers. Amateur coding around sensitive info might make you liable for any compromises. Please note that I am not an attorney. Please check out any info I offer in this regard with a qualified, competent, & licensed attorney at law in your jurisdiction.

That said, the super proper way to do what you are trying to do is to use mysql in tandem with php. Rather than write out a fully fleshed out answer on that, I would rather refer you to javascript, php, and msql as a topic.

Now to do what you want to do, this quick and dirty way with no expectation of basic  security:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hey</title>
<script>

function sendit()
{
if (document.getElementById("UserName").value == "")
{
alert("Please Enter Something in the Username Field");
}

if (document.getElementById("password1").value == "")
{
alert("Please Enter Something in the Password Field");
}

if (document.getElementById("UserName").value != "" && document.getElementById("password1").value != "")
{
my_form.action = "yourphpfile.php";
document.my_form.submit();

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Welcome User <br /> Please enter your username and password</h3>
<form method="post" name="my_form">
<h4>User Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserNameN" /></h4>
<h4>Password: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="password" id="password1" name="password1N" /></h4><br />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="sendit()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you need to make the php page:

```
<?PHP
$UserName = $_POST['UserNameN'];
$Password = $_POST['password1N'];

function redirect($url)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url);
   exit();
}

if ($UserName == "BobTim" and $Password == "Password")
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= 'BobTim';
redirect("abc123.html");
exit();
}


if ($UserName == "Blake" and $Password == "12345")
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= 'Blake';
redirect("abc123.html");
exit();
}

if ($UserName == "George" and $Password == "ABCDEFG")
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= 'George';
redirect("abc123.html");
exit();
}

if ($UserName == "Steve" and $Password == "ILikeBlue")
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= 'Steve';
redirect("abc123.html");
exit();
}

if ($UserName == "Coco" and $Password == "IceCream")
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= 'Coco';
redirect("abc123.html");
exit();
}


else {
redirect("sorry.html");
exit();
}
?>
```

After you redirect to abc123.html, you make abc123.html with this at the top:

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: http://www.mybusinesssample.com/forbidden.html');
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
echo "Hi {$_SESSION['username']} <br /><a href='unset.php'>Log Out</a><br /> <br />";
}
?>
```

Now, you need a logout page which in this case is called unset.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header ('Location: index.html');
?>
```

And if they don't make it through, you need to tell them sorry:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>

function sendit()
{
if (document.getElementById("UserName").value == "")
{
alert("Please Enter Something in the Username Field");
}

if (document.getElementById("password1").value == "")
{
alert("Please Enter Something in the Password Field");
}

if (document.getElementById("UserName").value != "" && document.getElementById("password1").value != "")
{
my_form.action = "yourphpfile.php";
document.my_form.submit();
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Welcome User <br /> Please enter your username and password</h3>
<form method="post" name="my_form">
<h4>User Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserNameN"/></h4>
<h4>Password: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="password" id="password1" name="password1N" /></h4><br />
Sorry! Your Username and/or your password wasn't recognized!   <br />
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="sendit()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, I would like to thank you for making this old, old project relevant again.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Are we using PHP just because?

Comment: If the op is a newbie, it's a great place to start with nothing to go on.

Comment: If someone could please tell me why they are down voting this answer, that would be great!

Comment: The question was asked about and tagged javascript, html and node.js, not about PHP. I would assume that's why you're getting down voted since the answer does not address those topics.

Comment: He is one week into web dev and has a whole answer in php. What difference does it make if it's php or node.js?

Comment: From MY understanding, this is the ONLY correct answer so far. The other answer does not do what I think the OP wants to do (the file is on his web server, not on the client). I particularly like using PHP here since it de-confuses the OP's notions of what runs in the server and what runs in the browser. Personally I think it's better than an actual node.js tutorial even though I prefer node and loathe PHP

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you may need to consider creating a desktop app to work with the website.

Reading in a text file with node.js on the client side, is very easy if you use either NW or Electron. These programs take your HTML +CSS + JS and produce an executable app that has access to node.js and a Chromium window.

So your desktop app could then communicate with your website.

NW:
https://nwjs.io/

Electron:
https://electronjs.org/

I use the former and it works like a charm. In fact the only trouble I ever get is from the countless Chromium bugs.